# Material Image Size relative to Button[codenameone]

Tags: java, codenameone

I use FontImage.setMaterialImage(...) or sometimes FontImage.createMaterialImage(...).

How can I ensure the material image size increases or its minimum size is 48x48 px.

Lukman Jaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest not thinking in pixels but thinking in millimeters as this make far more sense with varying screen sizes.

When you invoke code such as:

```
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(label, FontImage.MATERIAL_3D_ROTATION);
```

The image will get the size of the font assigned to the given label. So if the label is styled with a standard medium font (the default) the size will be system specific. To customize this do:

```
label.setUIID("MyFontUIID");
```

Then in the designer theme:

1. Add MyFontUIID
2. Select the Font tab and select any native font.
3. Select the size to be in millimeters or pixels to determine a fixed size to the icon. I would recommend millimeters for portability.